# if breakepoint is used only then method get properly executed in ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios5

I have an app in which I need To make a movie with frames, write that movie to document directory, pass the filepath to next view controller and then play the movie there.

its working fine in ios5 iphone. But when i use ***ios6 iPad*** the movie is written fine and saved to document directory well. 
but on next view player view shows blank screen.

I have a method that is called in background thread and in this method write movie method is called.
Is it a thread problem or any thing else. love receive any solution

Thank you